# Triangle inequality univalent

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, triangles, absolute-value

$|Z_1| = | \frac{v(1+\alpha)+ \sqrt{v^2(1+\alpha)^2-4\alpha}}{2}|$

I know that using triangle inequality method $|Z_1|$ is:

$|Z_1|= |\frac{v(1+\alpha)}{2}| + |\frac{\sqrt{v^2(1+\alpha)^2-4\alpha}}{2}|$

Case I: $-1 \leq \alpha \leq 0$ and  $0 < v <1$

Prove that $|Z_1| \leq 1$

Triangle inequality |x+y|=|x|+|y|

I've been stuck on this problem now for a couple of days and I'm having a difficult time proving this case. I was wondering if anybody can assistance me on this problem. I want to thank you ahead of time for your cooperation.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Corrections have been made.

Comment: What is "triangle inequality method" ? Besides, I don 't see any inequality .

Answer (score 1):

For $v\in (0,1)$ and $a\in [-1,0]$ we have  $\;-4 a\geq 0\;$, so $\; v^2(1+a)^2- 4 a\geq 0.$

For brevity let $v(1+a)=p.$  We have $p\geq 0.$

Therefore $|Z_1|=|\;\frac {1}{2}(p+\sqrt {p^2-4 a} \;)\;|=\frac {1}{2}(p+\sqrt {p^2-4 a}\;) =Z_1.$

$$\text {We have }\quad |Z_1|\leq 1 \iff  Z_1\leq 1\iff  \frac {1}{2}\sqrt {p^2-4 a}\leq 1-\frac {p}{2} \iff $$   $$\iff  \sqrt {p^2-4 a}\leq 2-p\iff  p^2-4 a\leq (2-p)^2\iff   $$ $$\iff  p^2-4 a \leq 4-4 p +p^2 \iff   -a\leq 1-p\iff $$  $$\iff  -a\leq 1-v(1+a) \iff v(1+a)\leq 1+a $$ which holds because $v>0$ and $1+a\geq 0 $.